# subdata of an image data is not nil, but I can't display it in UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsdata

I have a data of a UIImage that I have converted using
`UIImagePNGRepresentation(_:)`. This gave me the bytes of it, for example, 47,000 bytes.

If I added it back to a UIImageView, the images shows very well
Here is the code

```
let img = UIImage(named: "MyImage.png")
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!, 0.5)!
image.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

Now, if I used `subdata(_:)` function with an `NSRange` like this:

```
let partOfImage = imageData.subdata(with: NSRange(location: 2000, length: 22000))
image.image = UIImage(data: partOfImage)
```

This will not show the image in the UIImageView.

**My question is**: Why the subdata when it's converted to a UIImage, it still not showing up?

*Note: I know that I can use the image directly with the UIImageView, but I'm doing this for another purpose. Please, if you have any question of need further info, just comment below instead of down voting.*

Comment: Are you trying to crop the image ?

Comment: Are you using Swift2 ?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to display a part of the bytes to see the results, it's for another purposes

Comment: What you mean part of the bytes? You can't just get "part" of the image like this

Comment: I'm using Swift 3

Comment: Why? That's what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: What are you trying to do? crop or reduce size?

Comment: Just like I said, I just want to see the results of those bytes

Comment: You can see the value of the bytes but not an image

Comment: Does it have a reason? I'm trying to know the reason why I can't display an image out of bytes

Comment: The reason it is just a bunch of data. UIImage only supports the common known image types like PNG, JPEG, … not your Data junk

Comment: Okay got it, thank you

Comment: you are welcome https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/LoadingImages/LoadingImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH17-SW7

Comment: For instance, a JPEG files have some rules: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure It has to start with some bytes, end with others, etc. It's like writing `Hello I'm there!`, cutting the start, the end, and getting only `'`, not a valid sentence or logical one.